# How to upload a document via API to watson discovery services. ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm using the following API to upload a file to watson discovery services. I'm getting the response as unsupported file format, even though i have provided a valid type.
API:[discovery service api](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/?curl#add-doc)

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {

            //ADD BASIC AUTH
            var authByteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{auth key}");
            var authString = Convert.ToBase64String(authByteArray);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authString);

            var text = string.Empty;
            var uri = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{envid}/collections/{collectionid}/documents?version=2017-11-07";


            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Views/UploadDocument/civilwar-api1.html"));
            var file = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));
            content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/html");
            content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes)), "file");

            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
            var text1 = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }

        return View();
    }
```

api response as :`{
  "code" : 415,
  "error" : "Unsupported Media Type"
}`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Watson Developer Cloud, you can use the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk).

In this repository, you can see [examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/examples) for using each service from Watson.

The method to add a document:

```
#region Documents
        private void AddDocument()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\nCalling AddDocument()..."));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(_filepathToIngest))
            {
                var result = _discovery.AddDocument(_createdEnvironmentId, _createdCollectionId, _createdConfigurationId, fs as Stream, _metadata);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
                    _createdDocumentId = result.DocumentId;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("result is null.");
                }
            }
        }
```

- See more about [Watson Discovery](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/adding-content.html#adding-content).

Answer (score 0):

try `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .Accept
      .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header`

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation goes  long way in understanding the solution and how to solve similar issues in the future.